# Is there currently train service between Turkey and Iran?

Tags: trains, turkey, iran

According to [this website](http://seat61.com/Iran.htm) the train service between Istanbul and Tehran is suspended and the alternative company they propose makes its last stop in Turkey and requires guides to accompany people into Iran.

Are there any train services which still run from Turkey into Iran without requiring guides to transfer by land (on foot or bus presumably) ?

Comment: @pnuts yeah but you get off the train 235km from the Iranian border and have to be accompanied by someone to cross then take another train from Iran.

Comment: @pnuts Canadian

Comment: Your username is appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comments basically already spell out the answer, but, no. The Trans-Asia Express was the only train connection between Turkey and Iran.

Depending on your actual objective, I think you would be able to get a train up to the Iranian border in Azerbaijan, entering Azerbaijan via Russia.

Comment: So the train doesn’t actually cross into Iran ? We have a train here that runs between Canada and the US, you pass immigration on board and the same train crosses the border to continue to the US. I had something like that in mind.

Comment: @pnuts and as far as we know that was the last such service ?

Comment: Seat61's link (in OP's question) is pretty authoritative. The Turkey to Iran train was the only passenger train actually crossing into Iran. The Azeri connection currently halts at the border, as there are, yet, no tracks onwards. On the Turkmenistan side, new train tracks were recently inaugurated but, to my knowledge, are currently only used for goods.